# How to prove the demicountinuity of nonlinear operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

Define a nonlinear operator $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}):~\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ as
$$
\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}):= |\mathbf{x}|^{-\alpha}\mathbf{x},~0<\alpha<1.
$$
How to prove that $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x})$ is demicontinuous?
Demicontinuity of an operator $\mathbf{J}$ means that $\mathbf{x}_n \rightharpoonup \mathbf{x}$ (weak convergence) implies that $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x}_n) \rightharpoonup \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x})$ (weak convergence).

Comment: Is $\rightharpoonup$ the same as $\to$ (i.e. convergence in norm)?  How is this different than continuity (at least for metric spaces)?

Comment: This is a finite dimensional vector space, hence the weak and strong topology are the same.

Comment: Yes, $\rightharpoonup$ is the same as $\rightarrow$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*General fact*: if $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is a continuous function with $f(0)=0$, then the operator 
$$J(x) = \frac{f(\|x\|)}{\|x\|}x ,\quad f(0)=0 \tag{1}$$
is continuous (norm-to-norm topology). In finite dimensions, all locally convex topologies are the same, and with $f(t)=t^{1-\alpha}$ you get your claim.

The proof of general fact is not hard. At $x\ne 0$ the denominator does not vanish. The continuity at $0$  follows from $\|J(x)-J(0)\|=f(\|x\|)$ and the continuity of $f$.